# passport.deserializeUser is never called

Tags: session, cookies, passport.js

With passport.js I'm able to successfully redirect users to the successRedirect path, but as soon as the client gets redirected, my isAuth middleware immediately rejects them saying that req.isAuthenticated() is false.

This is my passport.js config file:

```
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const db = require('../db/connection.js')
const validPassword = require('./passwordUtil.js').validPassword

module.exports = function(passport){
    passport.use(new localStrategy(function verify(username,password,cb){
        db.any(`SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = '${username}';`)
            .then((results) => {
                if(results.length == 0){
                    return cb(null, false)
                }
                const isValid = validPassword(password, results[0].hash, results[0].salt)
                if(isValid){return cb(null, results[0])}
                else{return cb(null, false)}
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error)
                cb(error)
            })
    }))
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=>{
        console.log('!!!!!deserialize: ' + id)
        db.any(`SELECT * FROM players WHERE id = '${id}'`)
            .then((results) =>{
                if(results.length == 0){
                    return done(null, false)
                }
                const user = results[0]
                return done(null, user)
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                return done(error)
            })
    })
    passport.serializeUser((userObj, done) =>{
        console.log('*passport.js* serializeUser: ' + userObj.id)
        done(null, userObj.id);
    })
}
```

This is my server.js sessions section:

```
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const requestTime = require("./backend/middleware/request-time")


const session = require('express-session')
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session)
const db = require("./backend/db/connection.js")

const passport = require('passport')
require('./backend/config/passport')(passport)


const sessionStore = new pgSession({
  pool: db,
  tableName: 'sessions'
})

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: sessionStore,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4
  },
  rolling: true
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

These are my routes, the issue persists if I use the successRedirect, failureRedirect snippets originally provided:

```
router.post('/login', (req,res,next) =>{
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) =>{
    if(err) {
      console.log(err)
      return next(err)
    }
    if(!user){
      return res.redirect('/login-failure')
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
        return next(err)
      }
      console.log('*LOGIN* req.session: '+req.session)
      console.log('*LOGIN* req.user.id: ' + req.user.id)
      console.log('*LOGIN* req.isAuthenticated(): ' + req.isAuthenticated())
      req.session.save(()=>{
        res.redirect('/home')
      })
    })
  })(req,res,next)
})
router.get('/home',isAuth, (req,res)=>{
  console.log('*HOME* req.user: ' + req.user)
  console.log('*HOME* req.isAuthenticated(): ' + req.isAuthenticated())
  res.render('home', {user: req.user})
})
```

And these are the server logs:

```
[server:dev] Request recieved at 1682054920396: POST
[server:dev] *passport.js* serializeUser: a83dc705-c57c-44d9-b476-b46e9e574380
[server:dev] *LOGIN* req.session: [object Object]
[server:dev] *LOGIN* req.user.id: a83dc705-c57c-44d9-b476-b46e9e574380
[server:dev] *LOGIN* req.isAuthenticated(): true
[server:dev] POST /login 302 54.257 ms - 54
[server:dev] Request recieved at 1682054920436: GET
[server:dev] *isAuth* req.body: {}
[server:dev] *isAuth* req.user: undefined
[server:dev] *isAuth* Session: Session {
[server:dev]   cookie: {
[server:dev]     path: '/',
[server:dev]     _expires: 2023-04-21T09:28:40.434Z,
[server:dev]     originalMaxAge: 14400000,
[server:dev]     httpOnly: true
[server:dev]   }
[server:dev] }
[server:dev] *isAuth* req.session.passport: undefined
[server:dev] *isAuth* isAuthenticated(): false
[server:dev] GET /home 302 7.463 ms - 46
```

isAuth is just a middleware function calling req.isAuthenticated() and returning next if true.

Finally, inside my postgresql database sessions table we have the entry(sid, sess, expire):

FIwXB00wTn6vpkd7ixP2SP285EQ0IHSK | {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":14400000,"expires":"2023-04-21T09:05:40.337Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"passport":{"user":"a83dc705-c57c-44d9-b476-b46e9e574380"}} | 2023-04-21 02:05:41

As you can see, the *LOGIN* authentication succeeds, and we find the session in the database, but as soon as the isAuth middleware is called everything is 'lost'... Can someone help me understand why this is and how to fix the deserializeUser call?

It seems like I've tried everything... I don't know what else to try, if you do, please let me know